# Make cmd+| map to command in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

In Atom cmd+| maps to toggling the file tree, how can I make sublime text do the same when these keys are pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by toggling the file tree you mean hiding and showing the side bar, what you want to do is remap the key bound to the command that does that by default.

Note: Based on your use of `cmd` in the question, I'm assuming you're on a Mac so the answer is tailored for that. The operation remains the same but the key name will be different for the other platforms.

If you look at the default key bindings (available from the `Preferences` menu, which under MacOS is part of the `Sublime Text` menu entry) you can determine what keys are bound to what by default. In this case the command you want is `toggle_side_bar`; if you don't know the command you can find it by searching the key map to find the keys that you know you press to do this normally.

With that information, the default key binding for MacOS is:

```
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+b"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" },
```

In your own custom key bindings file (available from the same menu as the defaults) you just need to insert your own key binding. For your case, that would look like this:

```
{ "keys": ["super+\\"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" },
```

You might think that the key should be `super+|` since that is what you want to bind to ultimately; however that will not work because in order to generate that character, you need to be pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and thus without `shift` as a part of the key binding, it won't work.

Instead we use the character that is generated if you press the key without shift, which on my keyboard is `\`. That is a special character in JSON strings, so it needs to be doubled in order to be correct.

For keyboard layouts different from US QWERTY, you might need to swap that character for something else. You can determine the binding you want by opening the Sublime console with `View > Show Console`, entering the command `sublime.log_input (True)` and then pressing the key combination in question; Sublime will tell you what it thinks you pressed.